# .htaccess redirect issues with subdirectories

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I am trying to redirect the following...

- `http://example.com/blog/article-name` to
- `http://example.com/blog/news/article-name`

.. and this works fine..

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/news 
RewriteRule ^blog/(.*) /blog/news/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
```

It stops there being an infinite redirect loop...

However, I do not want the URL..

```
http://example.com/blog/
```

to redirect anywhere as this is my landing page to list all blog entries...  At the moment I get an infinite loop here.

`http://example.com/blog/news/news/news/news/news/news/news/news/news/news/news/news/news/news/news/news/news/news/`

I have tried adding in another condition to stop the root page being redirected...

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/$
```

but this does not work...

FYI

Here is my complete `.htaccess` file

```
# BEGIN WordPress
# The directives (lines) between `BEGIN WordPress` and `END WordPress` are
# dynamically generated, and should only be modified via WordPress filters.
# Any changes to the directives between these markers will be overwritten.
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/news 
RewriteRule ^blog/(.+) /blog/news/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Any ideas?

Comment: These directives alone will not result in a "redirect loop". This is more likely due to a conflict with other directives. Please edit your question to include the entire contents of your `.htaccess` file and any other `.htaccess` you might have along the filesystem path.

Comment: No probs... should have said its a simple WP site...

Comment: Do `/blog` and `/blog/news` exist as physical directories, or are they part of WordPress virtual URLs?

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/news 
> RewriteRule ^blog/(.*) /blog/news/$1 [QSA,L,R=301]
> ```

These directives should not cause a *redirect loop* when requesting `/blog/`, however, they will redirect you to `/blog/news/`. To prevent this undesirable redirect you can simply change the subpattern `.*` (0 or more) to `.+` (1 or more), so that it matches `/blog/<something>` and not `/blog/<anything>`.

In other words:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/blog/news 
RewriteRule ^blog/(.+) /blog/news/$1 [L,R=301]
```

The `QSA` flag is not required here since you are not adding a query string in the *substitution* string.

**UPDATE:** You've put the directives in the wrong place - they need to go *before* the `# BEGIN WordPress` section, at the very top of your `.htaccess` file. By placing them at the end they simply aren't going to get processed.

However, this still isn't the cause of the redirect loop.

You do, however, need to make sure you've cleared your browser cache. Any erroneous 301s (perhaps during testing) will have been persistently cached by the browser. First test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid cching issues.

Comment: I've updated my answer. The redirect directives are in the wrong place. And you do need to make sure you've cleared your browser cache.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help...   I have resolved this issue, by changing new root path, so there is no conflict, and my redirects work fine now.   I think the issue I was experiencing was actually to do with cached urls routes in Chrome which are still happening in Incog mode, so even though I was making changes i was still being routed to previous settings.

Comment: What do you mean by "changing new root path"?